# issues with iterative code in java

Tags: java

I want to convert the recursive function given below:

```
 LinkedList i=a; //a contains the nodes which are adjacent to the last element of g
 for(String i1: i )
{
  if(g.contains(i1) || i1.equals("o"))
   { continue; }
  g.addLast(i1);
  func(g);
  g.removeLast();
}
```

I want to convert the above program to an iterative one. Can someone help

Comment: For starters, `while(g.isEmpty())` will never occur at all, because you add something to `g` immediately before that loop.  It's very unclear what all the variables here are meant to do, and I'm pretty sure you get variables switched around in several lines here.

Comment: _program does not seem to work_? What is the specific problem you are facing? error? Exception?

Comment: @GrailsGuy Its clearly not Homework

Comment: You should use better variable names, the way you have it makes it tough to read.

Comment: You can only do a simple translation like this when the recursion happens at the end or beginning of the process. This allows you to build up a stack and then empty it. When doing a half before and half after recursion, you need to separate out those aspects of your algorithm. Do all of the pre-stuff, stacking post actions appropriately, then doing all of your post-stuff in a second loop.

Comment: @Guvante Yes correct..but i m not getting how to...can you direct me to some good examples...thanks for being helpful

Comment: @Asif I have written there..its because of some logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LinkedList i=a; //a contains the nodes which are adjacent to the last element of g
   for(String i1: i )
   {
      if(g.contains(i1) || i1.equals("o"))
       { continue; }
      g.addLast(i1);
      func(g);
      g.removeLast();
   }
```

So walking through this it appears as though the steps are as follows:
1) Check for existence of current String or if it equals "o"
2a) If yes continue
2b) else put current string at end of list.
3)  repeat steps 1->2
4) remove the last element of the list

If I were to make the code as simple as possible given those steps it would look like so:

```
func(LinkedList ll)  
{  

    Set set = new HashSet(ll);  //removes all duplicates  
    if(set.contains("o")  {  set.remove("o") ;}  //these are strings so that works
    LinkedList newLL = new LinkedList(set);  //order still retained  
    newLL.poll();  //remove last element
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your code, it finds all the available paths, right ?

The main 2 issues I see in your 2nd code are :

- In the recursive version, you handle the path with currentNode by calling func, then remove currentNode. In the iterative version, you put visitedNodes in the stack "to be handled", and then alter visitedNodes before it was handled !
- Related issue : you're always stacking over and over the same visitedNodes

So some solutions would be to put in the stack a copy of visitedNodes + the element currentNode.
visitedNodes will not be altered this way

I can do a bit of code if needed

Comment: Well, you can still print the copy of the visited nodes. The main concept here is to fill the "to handle stack" with all "possible path from the currently handled", then let the loop take another path and do the process again. So each path should be immutable, and every "new possibility" being a copy of the current path + the next possible move